# Android, "ndk-build" not found in PATH

Tags: android-ndk

Got this error:
Error: Program "ndk-build" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:\Android\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r9-windows-x86-legacy-toolchains\android-ndk-r9;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;...]

I have tried to set path to download the "bigger" package, but my eclipse can't recognize that. Any one know how to help me out? I have updated eclipse and the SDK for Android Tools

Answer (score 0):

ndk-build should be in the root of the NDK, from your path above Add C:\Android\AndroidNDK and it should find it.

Comment: It is the Root, AndroidNDK is just a dir that I made for myself to get better order. Could it be that I am using win7? I saw at "Android Developers" that only winXP and Vista are supported operating systems of Windows

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ndk-build.cmd` instead of just `ndk-build`.

Comment: Do you have more details on why?